# QT and heap corruption

Tags: c++, qt, heap-corruption

I understand that heap corruption can happen from wide variety of causes.

I have a QT C++ project in Visual Studio. If I run in Debug or Release mode from Visual Studio, everything goes smoothly.

If I run the released executable (outside of Visual Studio), I get an application has stopped working error, followed by a prompt that asks if I want to Debug. This brings up *Visual Studio Just-in-Time Debugger* window stating that: `An unhandled win32 exception occured in my_qt_application.exe[8812]`

If I choose to Debug, I get the message: `Unhandled exception at (...) (ntdll.dll) (...) A heap has been corrupted.`

So I keep searching in the code for causes. The problem is that this error happens at very random occasions, not very consistent.

My question is; *can* the cause of this be missing dlls? (I've added the dlls that allows the program to run.)

Comment: You could have dlls in your path that are built from a different compiler than what you built your code from. If these are being loaded with your project you will have UB because of more than 1 CRT being used at the same time and also possible stl incompatibilities.

Comment: Rather than just copying the DLLs, I would recommend using [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) which automatically grabs dependencies for you. That way you're guaranteed to have the same libraries in your deployment as in your development machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The cause cannot be missing dlls. It could be a proximate cause. Example: If some image plugins are not available, and your code doesn't check that `QImage` loading had succeeded, and then tries to operate on the null image - there may be problems.

Most likely, though, you have a plain old memory error that you should squish using e.g. Valgrind.

Comment: You won't find Valgrind for Windows, but you may find some substitutes that do sort of the same thing.  See [this question on Valgrind Substitute for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) for some ideas.

Comment: You were of course right, it was some memory/wrong casting errors. Didn't get Valgrind to work as stated above. Tried to get Windbg to work, but not luck. I ended up spending half a day on this issue by checking the code, think it is solved now!

Comment: You should have little trouble compiling it on a Linux platform, I'd think - unless you use some Windows APIs directly. Even then, you might be able to link with wine libraries to cover them.